Tire keeps dislodging from rim

I recently bought a bike, and the rear tire keeps dislodging from the rim. Near where the tire separates, I found a small divet in the rim. When I run my finger on the inside of the rim, I can feel a small bump on the inside as well. Is this enough to cause the tire to separate from the rim? If so, how can I fix this?

What is the approximate age of the tire? Folding or steel bead ? The dent while not ideal will not be the cause of the roll-off.

I'm not sure about the age of the tire, but it seems to be in pretty good shape. I believe that it is a folding bead (If you can bend it in half, its folding, right?).
I talked to a friend and he suggested that the size of the tire might not match the rim, but they are both 24" from what I know. Is there some variation where they still might not match?

Sizes in inches are not very precise, maybe take the rim to a shop where they sell tires and fit one there.

Can you say a bit more about how the tire comes unmounted? When you mount it, is it a very loose fit? Is it that when you pump it up, one of the beads climbs off the side and the tube blows out?

Yes, that's exactly right. When I pump it up, it seems like the tube just pushes it right out. When I mount it, it seems pretty snug. To take it off, I do have to work it a bit.

Possibly if the tyre is old enough, the Kevlar bead has stretched and degraded enough that it no longer conforms to the rim.
You could confirm by using the tyre from the other wheel. If it mounts well then you know the problem is the tyre.
I have done this to a 26” folding tyre pre-tubeless when an unlucky day might see 3 or more punctures. Eventually the bead just wouldn’t hold onto the rim.
This won’t make much sense if the tyre has not seen above average on/off cycles.

I believe this is the case. On further inspection, I saw that at one portion of the tire, the bead seemed to be worn down and was rather flat.
